# MVC4 Why have separate script bundles

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, scriptbundle

This is just for interest sake.

Why does the vanilla MVC template in VS split the script bundles into

```
ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery")
```

and

```
("~/bundles/jqueryval")
```

I realize that most pages won't need the jqueryval bundle, but minified its so small that you may as well include it in the main bundle and just cache it right from the start, or am I missing some more important reason?

Comment: This is a great question.  Too bad it didn't receive any answers